# How to update the document ID in firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

in my firestore database, I've made the user's email as the document key. Do if I want I cal do `db.collection('users').doc('email_id')` to perform some action. Now the problem is when the user is updating their email id, I am not finding any way to update the `document id` in firestore.

I've tried to do

```
db.collection('users').doc(old_email).update({
  id: new_email
})
```

But that actually created a new field called `id` with the new email as value inside that document instead of updating the actual `document id` so that I can pass it within `doc()` and get the same data about the user.

Does anyone know how to do it? If so, please do share.

before posting this question I have checked google and firestore docs but didn't find any way to update the document id. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to Change the Document ID, but even if there is a way what you do is horribly wrong. The ID should be a Unique Identifier, make yourself a UserID Field, for example with Firebase Auth use `firebase.Auth().currentUser.uid` as the ID of your User specific saved data in the Firestore.

I Suggest you to Change that in General that solves your Problem and more importantly gives you a solid structure. (The UID from the Auth is Unique)

Comment: Well, I made the email id as the doc id is because I wanted it to be unique and it won't duplicate. So, you are saying there is no way to do it?

Comment: @iSaumya The Thing is the E-Mail can Change and you have a ton of extra work to go around that. The User ID is Unique and wont be changed. I did no Research on if it is possible to do but having a Key that can Change is bad practise already and i dont think Firebase has a Workaround for it.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. I guess I have to fix my code then  and use the auth uid as the doc it

Comment: @iSaumya Yes i also have some Projects with Firebase and using the UID with user related data is simply the best. Because reading out data of logged in users is no Problem because you can get the uid as easy as the email, additionally any Auth data the user changes has no influence on the ID so you dont Need to Change any additional stuff.

Btw if you really wanna use the E-Mail then you would have to copy the doc of the user into a temp var, delete the doc and create a new doc with the new email as key and then paste the old doc in it but as you see its simply unneccessary work.

Comment: I have another question which is not in scope of this querstion but still asking in hope you can help. Firestore doc said that it's better to add a timestamp as a field as it will sort the docs on basis of that. Is it talking about `Date.now()` or something else? See the important note: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document

Comment: @iSaumya I think it refers to the fact that in the old Realtime DB the Docs were sortable via the ID, which is not the case in the new Firestore DB, `If you want to be able to order your documents by creation date` = if you think you will Need to order your documents for creation date then it is smart to Add a timestamp field otherwise you wont Need it. Keep in mind that if you wanna order your users by creation date you can simply use the creation date from the Firebase Authentication

Comment: And if I need I can add the timestamp with `Date.now()` correct? No need to require firebase-admin

Comment: @iSaumya Yes just store it as an extra field when you Set/Add the new Document. Keep in mind that `Date.now()` only Returns the number of milliseconds since 1970 so you cant properly store it in a date type field in your DB. Just Google how to get a good Date Format in Javascript.

Answer (score 66):

There is no API to change the ID of an existing document, nor is there an API to move a document. If you want to store the same contents in a different document, you will have to:

1. Read the document from its existing key.
2. Write the document under its new key.
3. Delete the document under its old key.

You'll want to run these operations in a transaction, to ensure the operations complete atomically.

Comment: I was hoping there was an option to update the existing document ID, but with that said I'll settle for this answer. You can have my updoot

Comment: Another solution, which I had implemented is have two different documentIDs (documentID and documendUID).  DocumentUID is used in queries and can be change as needed (used as a field within the document) and the other documentID doesn't change and is primarily used to define the document itself.  I also created a "translation" document that has the documentUID as the identifier for a document and has both the documentID and documentUID as fields.  I use this to translation requests for the documentUID and if I need to reference the documentID I can simply read this document.

Comment: Sounds like the basis for a great answer @BrianBegun :)

Comment: Note: This will only copy document top level data. You will lose all sub-collections within the original document if you do this.