# updating storage with the use of io fotoapparat library | Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I make a mobile application using the "io fotoapparat" library and I want to create a document with a random id and in the document in the id field, add the document id, the photo we will take was updated in the firebase store and in the previously made about the same id in the receipt collection when taking a photo

[link from which I took "io fotoapparat"](https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/camera-app)

EDIT
add to firestore document

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            val biedronka = "biedronka"
            val price = "20"
            val img = " "
            val identificator = " "

            val from = biedronka
            val value = price
            val image = img
            val idd = identificator

            val db = Firebase.firestore
            val data = hashMapOf(
                "from" to from,
                "value" to value,
                "image" to image,
                "id" to idd
            )

            db.collection("receipts")
                .add(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                    Log.d(SCAN_DEBUG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: ${documentReference.id}")
                    db.collection("receipts")
                        .document(documentReference.id)
                        .update("id", documentReference.id)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                        }

                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.w(SCAN_DEBUG, "Error adding document", e)
                }
        }
```

2 add to storage and to document (doesnt work)

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val uid = profileVm.user.value?.uid!!
            val imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            val userImage = binding.userImg


            val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            val result = imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
            val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()

            if (result) profileVm.uploadUserPhoto(byteArray, "$uid.jpg")


    }

    }
```

repository to 2

```
fun uploadReceiptPhoto(bytes: ByteArray) {
        storage.getReference("receipts")
            .child("${docId}.jpg")
            .putBytes(bytes)
            .addOnCompleteListener{
                Log.d(REPO_DEBUG, "COMPLETE UPLOAD PHOTO")
            }
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                getReceiptPhotoDownloadUrl(it.storage)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(REPO_DEBUG, it.message.toString())
            }
    }
    private fun getReceiptPhotoDownloadUrl(storage: StorageReference) {
        storage.downloadUrl
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                updateReceiptPhoto(it.toString())
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(REPO_DEBUG, it.message.toString())
            }
    }
    private fun updateReceiptPhoto(url: String) {
        cloud.collection("receipts")
            .document(docId)
            .update("image", url)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d(REPO_DEBUG, "UPDATE USER PHOTO")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(REPO_DEBUG, it.message.toString())
            }
    }
```

THE REST OF THE CODE (camera code "io fotoapparat" and take pictures)

```
class ScanFragment : Fragment(), OnReceiptsItemAdd {

    private var _binding: FragmentScanBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val scanVm by viewModels<ScanViewModel>()

    private val SCAN_DEBUG = "SCAN_DEBUG"

    private var fotoapparat: Fotoapparat? = null
    private var fotoapparatState: FotoapparatState? = null
    private var cameraStatus: CameraState? = null
    private var flashState: FlashState? = null

    private val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentScanBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


        createFotoapparat()

        cameraStatus = CameraState.BACK
        flashState = FlashState.OFF
        fotoapparatState = FotoapparatState.OFF


        binding.fabSwitchCamera.setOnClickListener {
            switchCamera()
        }

        binding.fabFlash.setOnClickListener {
            changeFlashState()
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun createFotoapparat(){
        val cameraView = binding.cameraView

        fotoapparat = Fotoapparat(
            context = requireContext(),
            view = cameraView,
            scaleType = ScaleType.CenterCrop,
            lensPosition = back(),
            logger = loggers(
                logcat()
            ),
            cameraErrorCallback = { error ->
                println("Recorder errors: $error")
            }
        )
    }

    private fun changeFlashState() {
        fotoapparat?.updateConfiguration(
            CameraConfiguration(
                flashMode = if(flashState == FlashState.TORCH) off() else torch()
            )
        )

        flashState = if(flashState == FlashState.TORCH) FlashState.OFF
        else FlashState.TORCH
    }

    private fun switchCamera() {
        fotoapparat?.switchTo(
            lensPosition =  if (cameraStatus == CameraState.BACK) front() else back(),
            cameraConfiguration = CameraConfiguration()
        )

        cameraStatus = if(cameraStatus == CameraState.BACK) CameraState.FRONT
        else CameraState.BACK
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        if (hasNoPermissions()) {
            requestPermission()
        }else{
            fotoapparat
                ?.takePicture()
                ?.toBitmap()
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (hasNoPermissions()) {
            requestPermission()
        }else{
            fotoapparat?.start()
            fotoapparatState = FotoapparatState.ON
        }
    }

    private fun hasNoPermissions(): Boolean{
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun requestPermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), permissions,0)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        fotoapparat?.stop()
        FotoapparatState.OFF
    }


}





enum class CameraState{
    FRONT, BACK
}

enum class FlashState{
    TORCH, OFF
}

enum class FotoapparatState{
    ON, OFF
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: @AlexMamo look my edits , I use MVVM structure

Comment: @AlexMamo document adds nicely, but I don't know what's wrong with code 2 and repository that
- there is no adding photo to the strage and document
-I don't know how to make the added photo in storage have the id of the newly created document

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to achieve but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114590/how-to-update-the-document-id-in-firebase-firestore) other question explaining how to change the ID of a document, and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) documentation on how to update a document. Please let me know if it helps.