# How can i change document id in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I change document ID in firebase? I have human readable document IDs which contains characters that are problematic, eg non latin or "-" which disappear after I deslugify them, how can i change them. I try to do it directly in the console but I don't seem to be able to, can i do it programatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once a document has been created, you cannot modify document ID's. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114590/how-to-update-the-document-id-in-firebase-firestore).

What you can do instead is read in the old document, create a new one with the ID you want and the data from the original, and then delete the original. You will want to do these actions within a transaction to make sure that they are completed in their entirety.